# Postfix Relay acces denied on only one server with identical setups

Tags: postfix

I'm in the process of setting up a postfix server for my two servers. To ensure I have identical setups I try to avoid manual command settings and build and run an Ansible playbook with the necessary changes.

However, right now I'm having a weird problem: one server systematically rejects a test email while the other accepts an email from the same email address.

Both servers are set up to forward emails to virtual users to external addresses, like `admin@mydomain.com` to `person1@gmail.com` and `info@mydomain.com` to `person2@hotmail.com` etc.

Both servers use opendkim and postsrsd to play nice to Google when forwarding email to gmail addresses.

No Dovecot setup and such.

I've tested with 1 email address from a trusted ISP, sending a testmail to `info@mydomain.com` for both servers. Both servers forward the email to a gmail address of mine.

Both servers say:

```
connect from [my ISP email server]
Untrusted TLS connection established from [my ISP email server]: TLSv1 with cipher DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA (128/128 bits)
```

The 'good' server proceeds and logs postsrsd and opendkim actions and finally sends the email to my gmail address: `status=sent`

The 'bad' server immediately logs:

```
NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from [my ISP email server]: 554 5.7.1 [virtual address]: Relay access denied;
```

Both `main.cf` and `master.cf` of both servers are identical (except for the hostname and domain). 
Both use the same opendkim and postsrsd configuration.

Where else can I look to find out why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it took me hours to find, I'll put the answer here to help others:

turns out I moved the virtual domain setting from inline in main.cf to a separate file. Something went wrong in the Ansible playbook so the file ended up being empty (i.e. just comments, no domain definition). Once I've entered the domain, all worked as before.

ie: `virtual_alias_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_domains`

pointed to a file that contained no entry. After entering my domain name:

`mydomain.com  OK`

and using postmap etc. to tell postfix to pick it up, all worked.